# How to order a stacked barplot in R?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I couldn't find the answer to this problem, so I'm posting it.

I have a stacked [barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT75h.jpg) that I use to compare the occurrence of different values in my data

Now, I would like to order it in a decreasing order, starting with the biggest combined value. I tried using the method I use for normal barplots:

```
barplot(combined[order(combined, decreasing = T)],
    horiz = T,
    las=1,
    xlim = c(0,60),
    col = c('lightblue','darkblue'))
```

but it produces a barplot that is [no longer stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPSEu.jpg)

Is there a way to order it properly? I've seen some solutions with ggplot, but I'd prefer sticking to standard barplots, if it's possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your data as well

Comment: Check this link as well: http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/creating-stacked-barplot-and-grouped-barplot-in-r-using-base-graphics-no-ggplot2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a matrix inside `barplot()` function. When you use order and compute `combined[order(combined, decreasing=T)]` the result is a vector. If you want to order your columns with no regard to which color would have precedence you may use this code:

```
barplot(combined[,order(apply(combined, 2, max))])
```

What this does is to apply the function `max()` on the columns (margin 2, margin 1 would be rows) of your matrix. Then you'll have a matrix ordered by the maximum value of each column.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help! Please do not forget to choose the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following example to explain the method

```
num <- c(1, 8, 4, 3, 6, 7, 5, 2, 11, 3)
cat <- c(letters[1:10])
data <- data.frame(num, cat)
```

Now, to generate barplot in decreasing order

```
barplot(data[order(data[,1],decreasing=FALSE),][,1],names.arg=data[order(data[,1],decreasing=FALSE),][,2], horiz = TRUE)
```

[image]

Hope this example helps.